# Why use the pip command in the conda environment python3.6 will always prompt error？

Tags: python, anaconda

I am using Anaconda to install tensorflow-gpu, but after creating a new python3.6 environment under conda, every time I call the pip command, the following prompt will be displayed, but this prompt will not affect the execution of the command.

I tried to install python3.5 and python3.7 in the same environment and there is no such problem.And the following is the error message:

```
Error processing line 1 of 
C:\Users\Ning\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\protobuf- 
3.7.0-py3.6-nspkg.pth:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "D:\Code_Software\Anaconda\envs\tensorflow_bak\lib\site.py", 
line 168, in addpackage
      exec(line)
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 557, in module_from_spec
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'loader'
```

Answer (score 0):

Emm, when I delete this file

> C:\Users\Ning\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\protobuf-3.7.0-py3.6-nspkg.pth

The error message disappeared automatically. So I think this just beacause this left files which is not deleted before.